# Google forms not loading in every browser that I`ve used

Tags: google-forms

I've tried every solution by google regarding this problem (clearing web data, disable extensions and so on). Still I cannot access google forms and I get the following message below:

[image]

I've also tried different browsers (Edge and Firefox) and the problem remains.

One important detail is that my organization has been blocking access to some of Google's features (Google Docs, Google Drive etc.) with Kapersky. But I'm not receiving a block message (as you can see above) and other employees are able to access google forms.

What are the reamaining the possibilities that might solve this issue?

Comment: F12 > See console tab  for any errors. See network tab for what got blocked. Post text+screenshots in your question, if you find anything.

Comment: What is the actual URL you are trying to access?  eg. [https://docs.google.com/forms/](https://docs.google.com/forms/). Also provide more details around *"organization has been blocking access to some of Google's features (Google Docs, Google Drive etc.)"*  Specifically what do you mean when you use the term *"features"*